# COBOL ADD statement is not using correct field from record?

Tags: cobol

So I'm writing this program for class and I believe I have it right. But I can't test it because I can't do anything with one of my fields from an input record. I need to add it to different positions in an array but since it is using the wrong field I get an "invalid character in numeric field" error. I have the input record PIC clauses correct too. The input file is coded:

```
FD SALES-AMT-FILE-IN.
01 SA-SALESMAN-NUM-IN                  PIC 99.
01                                     PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
01 MONTH-NUM-IN                        PIC 9.
01                                     PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
01 SALES-AMT-IN                        PIC 9(5).
```

SALES-AMT-FILE-IN is laid out exactly like that I've checked it multiple times and checked each record. The section of code I'm getting the error in is:

```
440-READ-SALES-AMT-FILE.
    MOVE 'YES' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS

    PERFORM UNTIL ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS = 'NO' 
       READ SALESAMT-FILE-IN
           AT END
               MOVE 'NO' TO ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS
           NOT AT END
              DISPLAY SALES-AMT-IN *I coded this in to check what was in SALES-AMT-IN
              ADD SALES-AMT-IN TO A-AMT (MONTH-NUM-IN, SA-SALESMAN-NUM-IN)
       END-READ
    END-PERFORM.
```

The first record of the input file is like this:

```
30 1 17960
```

The display statement is giving me:

```
30 1
```

I can't figure out why the wrong data is going in there when I have the PIC correctly defined. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong. I'll post the entire code if needed.

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                   
01 ARE-THERE-MORE-RECORDS        PIC X(3)   VALUE 'YES'.   
01 PAGE-CTR                      PIC 99     VALUE ZERO.    
01 NUMBER-OF-LINES               PIC 99     VALUE ZERO.    
01 QTR-NUM                       PIC 9.                    
01 NAME-SUB                      PIC 9(3)   VALUE 1.       
01 NUM-SUB                       PIC 9(3)   VALUE 1.       
01 SALESMAN-NUM                  PIC 999.                  
01 SALESMAN-TOTAL                PIC 9(6).                 

01 WS-DATE.                                                
    05 RUN-YEAR                  PIC XX.                   
    05 RUN-MONTH                 PIC XX.                   
    05 RUN-DAY                   PIC XX.                   

01 HEADING-LINE-1.                                         
    05                           PIC X(17)  VALUE SPACES.  
    05                           PIC X(35)                 
        VALUE 'SALES AMOUNTS BY SALESMAN AND MONTH'.       
    05                           PIC X(6)   VALUE SPACES.  
    05 HL-DATE.                                            
        10  MONTH-HL             PIC XX.                   
        10                       PIC X      VALUE '/'.     
        10  DAY-HL               PIC XX.                   
        10                       PIC X      VALUE '/'.     
        10  YEAR-HL              PIC XX.                   
    05                           PIC X(3)   VALUE SPACES.  
    05                           PIC X(5)   VALUE 'PAGE'.  
    05  PAGE-NUMBER-HL           PIC Z9.                   

01 HEADING-LINE-2.                                         
    05                           PIC X(29)                 
        VALUE 'NUM  NAME'.                                 
    05 THREE-MONTH-NAMES.                                  
        10 MONTH-1-HL            PIC X(11).                
        10 MONTH-2-HL            PIC X(11).                
        10 MONTH-3-HL            PIC X(11).                
    05                           PIC X(5)   VALUE 'TOTAL'. 

01 DETAIL-LINE.                                            
    05 SALESMAN-NUMBER-DL        PIC ZZZ.                  
    05                           PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.  
    05 SALESMAN-NAME-DL          PIC X(20).                
    05 MONTH-1-AMT-DL            PIC ZZZ,ZZZ.              
    05                           PIC X(4)   VALUE SPACES.  
    05 MONTH-2-AMT-DL            PIC ZZZ,ZZZ.              
    05                           PIC X(4)   VALUE SPACES.  
    05 MONTH-3-AMT-DL            PIC ZZZ,ZZZ.              
    05                           PIC XX     VALUE SPACES.  
    05 AMOUNT-TOTAL-DL           PIC Z,ZZZ,ZZZ.            

01 SALESMAN-TABLE                           VALUE ZEROS.   
    05 ENTRIES OCCURS 99 TIMES INDEXED BY X1.              
        10 T-SALESMAN-NUM        PIC 99.                   
        10 T-SALESMAN-NAME       PIC X(20).                

01 SALES-ARRAY.                                            
    05 A-SALESMAN-NUM  OCCURS 99.                          
        10 A-MONTH     OCCURS 3.                           
            15 A-AMT             PIC 9(6)   VALUE ZEROS.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that all of your fields are defined a level 01.

Try creating it in a structure like this.

```
FD SALES-AMT-FILE-IN.
01 SALES-RECORD
  02 SA-SALESMAN-NUM-IN                  PIC 99.
  02                                     PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
  02 MONTH-NUM-IN                        PIC 9.
  02                                     PIC X        VALUE SPACE.
  02 SALES-AMT-IN                        PIC 9(5).
```

Comment: That was it. I think I see why it won't work the way I had it. Thanks!

Comment: I would use `05` instead of `02`. It's an old programmer's trick - if for some reason down the road you need to add a group item definition, then you can do it without much effort (unless you are a stickler for indentation).

It's a throwback to the punched-card days.

Comment: I agree. I worked for one place that always used odd numbers for each level. We also named those empty spaces FILLER, instead of leaving the field name blank.

Answer (score 2):

Your File Description is named `SALES-AMT-FILE-IN` while you `READ SALESAMT-FILE-IN`. Can't see the rest of the code, but that just doesn't look correct.

Comment: Oops that was a typo when posting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on everything you've shown, you must have bad data. For example, your "1" is an "l" (L) or your "0" is an "O".

Comment: SALES-AMT-IN shouldn't even contain 30 1 because of the PIC clauses for the input file. It should contain 17960 but it doesn't. I thought the same thing you are thinking until I put in the display clause and saw that it's not even using the data I'm telling it to.